The origin of Joule heating from scattering
My understanding is that Joule heating originates from the transfer of electronic energy to the lattice. This post states that impurities contribute to the dissipation of electrical energy. However, in Tritt's book p.47 it is said that impurities do not have available energy levels so the interaction of electrons with impurities are totally elastic and hence electrons do not lose energy, thus it would seem that there is no electrical energy transferred to the lattice. My confusions are: What kinds of scattering contributes to Joule heating, and to what extent? Does only inelastic scattering contributes towards to Joule heating or does elastic scattering also contribute?

Electron-phonon scattering is a (quite common) thing that thermalizes the carriers and the lattice. An impurity, as a deviation from the perfect lattice, helps couple the two.

I'm not a solid state physicist so my take might be different than how the field uses the terminology. In Ashcroft and Mermin, they describe Joule heating as coming from whatever the scattering mechanism is in your theory. Drude theory would tell you that's electrons bouncing off ions. But all you really need is some scattering mechanism, and you call that Joule heating.

The following is a highly suggested viewpoint, but do check with an expert on the details.
The two statements are actually not in contradiction, despite being worded in such a way as to appear to be in direct contradiction.
To even start to understand the answer to your question, you need to know about the "displacement of Fermi surface" explanation of (DC) conductivity, and Matthiessen's rule. You can find the latter in Tritt's book.
I think Tritt's book is a bit haphazard. Usually, a good solid state physics textbook would put in a lot of effort to explain what electrons and phonons are doing in a crystal, because only when your general theory of conduction is sophisticated enough, will the predictions start to work. When the general theory works, you can easily obtain correct predictions for both electric and thermal conductivity, and so it makes no sense to have a book focusing only upon thermal conductivity without the electric part.
However, near the part you are referring to, it is quite readable.
The first thing you need to know, is that, if the relaxation time is vastly longer than the Bloch period, then there will be Bloch oscillations and almost no conductivity. The relaxation time can only be in so long if there are very few impurities and the system is very cold. No conduction, resistance is huge, current is very small, Joule heating $P=IV=V^2/R$ is tiny.
When the relaxation time is shorter than the Bloch period, which is the usual behaviour, then the result of applying a voltage difference, is that the Fermi surface gets displaced at steady state. The relaxation time, through the normal scattering and Umklapp scattering processes, is responsible for the overall displacement, and thus the conductivity of the system. These can be electron-electron scattering, electron-impurity scattering, or electron-phonon scattering; each individual contribution is summarised as an independent relaxation time and combined via Matthiessen's rule.
The steady state displacement of the Fermi surface directly dictates the current density in the system, via the conductivity. This, in turn, converts the Joule heating power into a quadratic form in the applied electric field, thus also the applied voltage difference. But this is not a microscopic view; Although each collision conserves energy and momentum, the result of a lot of collisions end up giving rise to the conversion of ordered energy into disordered heat energy. It could come in the form of directly generating heat in the form of phonons obeying a thermal distribution, or, when any (elastic) collision occurs, there is a tiny discrepancy in energy and momentum, which is absorbed by the entire lattice. This is especially the case with Umklapp scattering.
When it comes to microscopic particles collisions, the definition of elastic v.s. inelastic collisions changes slightly. Because of the strict conservation of energy and momentum on the microscopic scale, and particle indistinguishablity, it becomes natural to consider any collision to be elastic unless quantum numbers like (internal) energy levels, or particle identities, or whatnot, changes.
What Tritt's book is saying, is that the energy gaps in the system due to impurities considered is very big compared to the typical available energies and momenta relevant to the scattering. This means that the impurities stay stuck in a specific quantum state and contribute to the scattering as if they are elastic scatterers. In particular, they form the background ionic field such that the collisions could be modelled as an elastic Rutherford scattering. The usual way that Rutherford scattering is modelled, you have the heavy ion pinned in place and the electron is scattered elastically off it. In practice, this is simply the reduced mass treatment, and you have to slightly edit the scenario to take into account that the ion actually recoils. The collision is still called elastic, but a tiny bit of energy goes into heating up the ionic lattice. That contributes to the Joule heating.
As you can see, there is a lot to this.
